# Error with use strict command in angularJs File

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's wrong with my code? I don't uderstand. I did everything just as it is in [this guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y010): 
, but I get `Unexpected token ) MainController.js:42`.

Here's the code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('FindItApp')
  .controller('MainController',MainControllerFunction);



  function MainControllerFunction($scope,places){
    angular.extend($scope, {
      mapCenter:{
        lat: 40.741934,
        lng: -74.004897,
        zoom: 16
      },
      layers: {
        baselayers: {
          googleTerrain: {
            name: 'Google Terrain',
            layerType: 'TERRAIN',
            type: 'google'
          },
          googleHybrid: {
            name: 'Google Hybrid',
            layerType: 'HYBRID',
            type: 'google'
          },
          googleRoadmap: {
            name: 'Google Streets',
            layerType: 'ROADMAP',
            type: 'google'
          }
        }
      }
    });

    places.success(function(data){
      $scope.geodata = data;
      $scope.mapMarkers = geodataToMarkers($scope.geodata);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Fix your indentation.  You'll then discover that you're missing a `}`.

Comment: Yeah, 10 times i check this code and I don't see it:/ Thx for open my eyes

Comment: Posting links to your code helps to get the context, but you should always include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you miss `}` on that line

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the opening bracket for your [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

In line 42, fix it by changing

```
})();
```

to

```
}})();
```

Or if you actually fix the indentation of your code, it would look like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('FindItApp')
  .controller('MainController',MainControllerFunction);

  function MainControllerFunction($scope,places){
    angular.extend($scope, {
      mapCenter:{
        lat: 40.741934,
        lng: -74.004897,
        zoom: 16
      },
      layers: {
        baselayers: {
          googleTerrain: {
            name: 'Google Terrain',
            layerType: 'TERRAIN',
            type: 'google'
          },
          googleHybrid: {
            name: 'Google Hybrid',
            layerType: 'HYBRID',
            type: 'google'
          },
          googleRoadmap: {
            name: 'Google Streets',
            layerType: 'ROADMAP',
            type: 'google'
          }
        }
      }
    });

    places.success(function(data){
      $scope.geodata = data;
      $scope.mapMarkers = geodataToMarkers($scope.geodata);
    });
  } // <-- you previously had this closing bracket in line below, and the following closing bracket was missing.

})();
```